# Mac 10.6 - unable to install PHP intl

Tags: php, intl

I'm trying to install the PHP intl extension on Mac 10.6 "Snow Leopard" using the following command:

sudo pecl install intl

...but getting the following errors:

```
running: phpize
grep: /usr/include/php/main/php.h: No such file or directory
grep: /usr/include/php/Zend/zend_modules.h: No such file or directory
grep: /usr/include/php/Zend/zend_extensions.h: No such file or directory
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:
Zend Module Api No:
Zend Extension Api No:
Cannot find autoconf. Please check your autoconf installation and the
$PHP_AUTOCONF environment variable. Then, rerun this script.

ERROR: `phpize' failed
```

I am using the bundles Apache server with PHP 5.3.4.

Does anyone know how to install the intl extension?

Comment: Doesn't MAMP support intl out of the box?

Comment: It seems it doesn't, this link states that compilation is needed: http://szemian.wordpress.com/2011/03/21/compiling-intl-extension-for-mamp/

Comment: Hmm I couldve sworn it did.  I'll look into it

Comment: What about Homebrew? Anyone know it?

Comment: It looks like Zend Server CE is going to solve my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've installed Zend Server CE and everything works 100%.

I removed Zend Server CE later on, and used this instead:
http://php-osx.liip.ch/ which is specifically built for Mac OSX 10.6, and Symfony2 in mind.

This worked better for me in the end, as I'm a Netbeans user, this means I can use xdebug bundled with the liip distribution.

I found it a bit cumbersome getting xdebug installed on Zend Server CE, and also, the liip PHP installation doesn't install an additional Apache and MySQL, it uses what is already included with the OS.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about using [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/index.html) instead? It generally works better than Apple's bundled packages.

Comment: It depends, and I'm looking at the same possibility now, does MAMP come with the intl extension bundled?

Comment: It does. But cannot launch automatically in background on start. Point for Zs.

Comment: MAMP doesn't come with intl bundled.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing autoconf

brew install autoconf

Regards

Answer (score 0):

This might be an old post, but for me, I found the easiest option was to install PHP using the liip service (http://php-osx.liip.ch/).  Using one simple command, it installed the latest version of PHP, configured it with the existing apache server installed on my mac all along with the intl extension.  A number of hours frustration solved in a couple of minutes!